# Facebook Canvas Fluid Canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook

Has anyone built anything using the new "fluid canvas"?

Besides the [sample code](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/) not working in IE 8, are there any other problems with doing this?
I'm wondering if I would be nuts to build an application using this? I mean, what would I do, check the available width of the screen and do different things for every user?

Isn't this prone to error? Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

even for "fluid" canvas, it is very likely that we are not going to check the available width of the screen (as the screen/browser window can be resize dynamically by the user).

instead, as it is an iframe, it is exactly the same way how we should built the canvas / web page that meet our needs or show best to the user by making use of the full width of the browser window.